# Setting Environment Variables in TestCafe giving undefined value

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, testcafe, ui-testing

I am learning TestCafe and I am new to it.

I am trying to follow as it is mentioned here: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/access-environment-variables-in-tests.html

I have a code that runs on my windows machine!!

```
fixture`Getting Started`.page`http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;

test("My First Test", async t => {
    await t
    .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
    .click('#submit-button')
    .takeScreenshot();

    const articleHeader = await Selector('.result-content').find('h1');
    
    // Obtain the text of the article header
    let headerText = await articleHeader.innerText;
    console.log(process.env.DEV_MODE);
});
```

My Scripts Section is like this

```
"scripts": {
    "setnode": "set DEV_MODE=staging",
    "test:chrome": "npm run setnode & npx testcafe \"chrome --start-fullscreen\" e2e/tests"
  }
```

when I am running this command `npm run test:chrome`

I am getting output like this

```
ui-testcafe-poc@1.0.0 setnode C:\TestCafeProjects\ui-testcafe-poc set DEV_MODE=staging

 Running tests in:
 - Chrome 79.0.3945.130 / Windows 10

Getting Started  

undefined   

√ My First Test
```

why the console.log is writing as undefined instead of staging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ampersand symbol (`&`) in your script runs them in parallel. However, you need to run them sequentially by using the `&&` operand.

Also, npm scripts spawn the shell process under the hood (cmd on Windows) and the variable set by the `set` command lives only in its own session. The following script should work:

```
"scripts": {        
    "test:chrome": "set DEV_MODE=staging && npx testcafe \"chrome --start-fullscreen\" e2e/tests"
}
```